# <video> blacks out screen shortly when stopping on Firefox

Tags: firefox, html5-video

I have a simple webpage with an HTML 5 `<video>` element and simple Javascript for creating links to switch between videos and for making each video stop at predetermined times.

It **appears to work fine** on Chrome 94, Edge 99, and Vivaldi 4.3 (I am on Windows 10).
In my Firefox 91.7esr, **however**, when the video stops (at a stop time *or at the end*), **the screen will often black out for about 1 second**.
After that, everything continues normally.
It is the entire screen that blacks out, not only the Firefox window or the `<video>` element on the page.

This happens irregularly about one third of the times (and much less frequently also when the video *starts*).
**Why?**

The web page and the videos are local files.
The effect occurs no matter whether hardware acceleration is on or off in Firefox.
It happens also after a reboot.

Here is the respective code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <video id="pomalevi-video" height=540 controls>
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <br>
    <button onclick="pmlv_speed(pmlv_video, 1.0)">1.0x</button>
    <button onclick="pmlv_speed(pmlv_video, 1.7)">1.7x</button>
    <button onclick="pmlv_speed(pmlv_video, 2.0)">2.0x</button>
    <p onclick='pmlv_switch_to(1)'>start video 1</p>
    <p onclick='pmlv_switch_to(2)'>start video 2</p>

    <script>
      var pmlv_video = document.getElementById("pomalevi-video")
      var pmlv_video_idx = 1
      var pmlv_stoptimes = [[5.1, 8.5, 11.9], [17.0, 20.4]]  // list of list of floats: stop times in seconds

      function pmlv_pause_at_stoptimes() {
          for (var t of pmlv_stoptimes[pmlv_video_idx-1]) {
            if(pmlv_video.currentTime >= t && pmlv_video.currentTime <= t+0.5) {
              pmlv_video.pause()
              pmlv_video.currentTime += 0.5
            }
          }
      }

      function pmlv_speed(obj, factor) {
        obj.playbackRate = factor
      }

      function pmlv_switch_to(i, play=true) {
        pmlv_video.src = "v" + i + ".mp4"
        pmlv_video_idx = i  // select the relevant stoptimes
        pmlv_video.load()
        if (play) {
          pmlv_video.play()
        }
      }

      pmlv_video.addEventListener("timeupdate", pmlv_pause_at_stoptimes)
      pmlv_switch_to(1, false)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with my HTML or Javascript.
Rather, it appears to be a **hardware issue**:

- The problem occurred on an external monitor that is connected
  to my notebook via, first an **Icy Box IB-DK2403-C docking station**
  using USB-C and from there via HDMI.
- When I play the video on the **internal screen** of the notebook,
  the problem still occurs, but what is blacked out is still
  the *external* monitor, not the internal one having the Firefox window.
- If I connect the monitor to the notebook's HDMI output directly, rather than
  through the docking station, the problem disappears.
- Furthermore, the setup also appears to be sensitive to **audio** start/stop
  as well: I have seen the screen black out when Windows notification
  sounds were played.
- But the **video** still produces the effect with the sound turned off
  in the `<video>` element's controls, so apparently both audio and
  video starting or stopping can produce a blackout. Weird.
- Why the **other browsers** are immune to the problem? No idea. (Hints welcome!)

The reason why I did not understand this more quickly is
that I started testing my application only one day after
I had started using the docking station.
I had not yet noticed the blackouts that occurred at other times.